# How to do a POST request in HTML without opening a new tab

Tags: html

I am looking for a way to do a POST request in HTML by pressing a button, but have a problem. I want it to not open a new window of the URL I have it post to or open the link I have it post to. Any ideas? I have some code but is just a button that posts to a URL

CODE:

```
 <form action="http://google.ca" method="post" target="_blank">
  <div>
    <button>post</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Also, I am just starting out it HTML and know absolutely nothing about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="http://google.ca" id='idForm'>
      <div>
        <button type='submit' >post</button>
      </div>
     </form>
  </body>  
<script>

    $("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               }
             });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I also want it to not open the link that I have it post to.

Comment: Use ajax for doing it in the background

Comment: Could you give an example of the code for a post using ajax?

Comment: I've updated the code. Ive used jquery to submit the form. You can do it using Javascript as well by using XML Http request. Would suggest you to read further to understand how ajax works

Comment: Thanks a ton, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this attribute:

```
target="_blank"
```

This is the attribute that opens the new tab, whereas `_self` targets the current tab/window. Change your entire code to this:

```
 <form action="http://google.ca" method="post" target="_self">
  <div>
    <button>post</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to make it in the background, not open the link I have it post to.

Comment: So you want it to open a new tab, but the tab in the background? Like a CTRL/CMD click?

Comment: I would like the person who clicks the button to not see the page or have it in a new tab, opening it in the background then closing it or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `target="_blank"` from the form. The default is to submit on the same page:

```
 <form action="http://google.ca" method="post">
  <div>
    <button>post</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: I would not like it on the same page, I would like it to be in the background so you don't see the page I would like to post to.